# Nginx error 98. Can't bind to port 80

Tags: nginx

I've been working on adding https to one of my websites lately.  Everything looked A-OK, but when I restarted the server I noticed that only the site using http would show up, the other site wouldn't.  Running `sudo nginx` gave me this

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Weird.  Never saw anything like that before.
I tried looking around for answers, but I couldn't find anything.  I never installed Apache on this server, so we can rule that out, never bothered messing with IPv6, nothing really seems to work.

I tried to go back to listening on port 80, but the same errors kept popping up, only without the 443 business.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE**: I fixed it, I think.

So, I used a blog tutorial (http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/) to help me set up a nginx/gunicorn/django website long before I started any of this.  For whatever reason, I decided that I should change this line...

`proxy_pass http://hello` (note, note the actual name)

To this

`proxy_pass https://hello`

Because I was using https.  Unfortunately, that's hardly how it works at all.  So, when I changed things back to the old `proxy_pass http://hello` line, everything worked fine, and I now have https on my site.

It's worth nothing that if I run `sudo nginx` I still get the same errors as before, the "Address already in use" errors.  Still, everything seems to work.

May my moments of hair-pulling serve to help others with their troubles.

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -na | grep ".80"` - a server process (possibly old nginx?) is running already it seems.

Comment: Just tried it out, not sure if this output is interesting or not, but here's what I got

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

and also

`unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9280`